# The luminosity is not correct on simple plane using VBO

Tags: opengl, sdl, vbo

I have written a small OpengL test program using VBO. I have a spot in (0.0, 5.0, 0.0), a camera also in (0.0, 5.0, 0.0) which looks at the point (0.0, 0.0, 0.0). My plane is center in the position (0.0, 0.0, 0.0). So, normally, all pixels on the plane should have the same value. But it's not the case. I tried several code combinations and it's the same result.

Here's a picture of the scene :

[image]

As you can see the spot seems to be positionned on the left but it should be positionned as the camera. It's not logical.

Here's my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <gl/glew.h>

#define OFFSET_BUFFER(offset)   ((char*)NULL + (offset))

static GLfloat position[4] = {0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
static GLfloat diffuse[3] = {0.40f, 0.40f, 0.40f};
static GLfloat specular[3] = {0.80f, 0.80f, 0.80f};
static GLfloat emissive[3] = {0.00f, 0.00f, 0.20f};

const static int WIDTH = 640;
const static int HEIGHT = 480;

struct Vertex
{
    float x, y, z;
    float nx, ny, nz;
};

static Vertex   vertex[24] =
{
    -1.000000f, 0.000000f, 1.000000f,   //V1
    1.000000f, 0.000000f, 1.000000f,    //N1
    1.000000f, 0.000000f, 1.000000f,    //V2
    1.000000f, 0.000000f, 1.000000f,    //N2
    1.000000f, 0.000000f, -1.000000f,   //V3
    1.000000f, 0.000000f, 1.000000f,    //N3
    -1.000000f, 0.000000f, -1.000000f,  //V4
    1.000000f, 0.000000f, 1.000000f     //N4
};

static void     eventListener(SDL_Event *pEvent, bool *pContinue)
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(pEvent))
    {
        switch(pEvent->type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            *pContinue = false;
            break;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch (pEvent->key.keysym.sym)
            {
            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                *pContinue = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int             main(int ac, char **av)
{
    bool        continuer = true;
    SDL_Event   event;
    GLuint      vboID = 0;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("VBO tests",NULL);
    SDL_SetVideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 32, SDL_OPENGL);

    //Initialize projection

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    gluPerspective(60.0, (float)(WIDTH/HEIGHT), 1.0f, 1000.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //Initialize light settings

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, position);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_EMISSION, emissive);
    glMateriali(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 100);

    //Initialize VBO settings

    glewInit();

    int vertexSize = 4 * sizeof(Vertex);

    if (glIsBuffer(vboID) == GL_TRUE)
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &vboID);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexSize, vertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    //Loop

    while (continuer)
    {
        eventListener(&event, &continuer);

        glClearDepth(1.0f);
        glClearColor(0.13f, 0.12f, 0.13f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glLoadIdentity();    
        gluLookAt(0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        //Lock buffer
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), OFFSET_BUFFER(0));

        glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), OFFSET_BUFFER(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 24);

        glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        //Unlock buffer
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glFlush();
        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return (0);
}
```

The luminosity seems to work but the render is not correct. The values in the Vertex structure comes from an a simple plane mesh file exported from Blender so I think the data are correct. Does anyone can help me ?

Comment: "*So, normally, all pixels on the plane should have the same value.*" Why should they? You're using lighting with a point light; that means you'll get different color intensities across a surface.

Comment: I notice you set the `modelview` matrix *after* setting the light position. The light's position will be modified by the `modelview` matrix, though. Not sure if it matters, but thought I should mention it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes it was a mistake to say that, sorry. With the intensity of the light combinate to the close position (light) with the plane, the color of the plane should be white. I changed the position of the MODEL_VIEW and does not have any change. I updated my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Check your geometry and normal vectors.. Where are your normal vectors looking at? You have a very strange geometry and view setup, and also it's better to not make use of the old fixed-function pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a pair of problems with the provided source code:

- Normals are not normalized.
- Normals are pointing to an strange position (1, 0, 1), shouldn't they be pointing (0, 1, 0)?

The normals are used to compute a dot product with the light direction (among other things in the light equation). If your light is at (0, 5, 0) and your normals pointing to (1, 0, 1) this will generate a shaded colour as they make those vertices like facing the position (sqrt(2), 0, sqrt(2)), but your quad is facing (0, 1, 0).